# Difference between title and name in html href element

Tags: html, href, title

in an href in html, whats the difference between using

```
<a href="http://www.somesite.com/" name="The Name">
```

and

```
<a href="http://www.somesite.com/" title="The Name">
```

Is there any advantage to using one over the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look it up in the spec, or better yet a resource that condenses the spec a bit.  (And, then the spec if that isn't enough.)

```
title   text    Specifies extra information about an element
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

> The name attribute specifies the name
>   of an anchor.
>
> The name attribute is used to create a
>   bookmark inside a document.
>
> The href or the name attribute must be
>   present in the  tag

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_name.asp

So, the name of the anchor is used for links like `exampledomain.com/index.php#some_section`, which would bring that anchor into focus on the page.

Many modern browsers will display the title attribute in a tooltip when hovering over the link.  It's likely also useful for screen readers and such.

Answer (score 2):

markup tag Node 

 - Name -- is to identify the element and for lookup

 - title -- is default toolTip property. like ALT